# Smooth UITableView Cell Expansion With Accordion Style

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

My table view can expand and collapse cells when they are pressed, but the content that appears when the cell expands loads before the animation is finished.

What I am left with is this:

[image: UITableView accordion expansion]

What I would like it to look like is [this example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u34Fw9biD3k&feature=youtu.be). This content appears as if it were behind a curtain and the cell expansion animation just reveals it.

Here is the code that controls the table view:

```
class HistoryViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{

    var expandedIndexPath: NSIndexPath? // Index path of the cell that is currently expanded
    let collapsedHeight: CGFloat = 44.0 // Constant to set the default collapsed height
    var ticketHistoryService = TicketHistoryService() // Service to gather info about Ticket History CoreData

    var tickets = [Ticket]()

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Remove any appended table view cells
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()

        self.tickets = self.ticketHistoryService.fetchData() // Load inital data

    }

    // MARK: - Table View Methods

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.tickets.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! HistoryTableViewCell

        let ticket = self.tickets[indexPath.row]

        cell.titleLabel!.text = ticket.ticketNumber
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .Delete {
            self.ticketHistoryService.removeObject(indexPath.row)
            self.tickets = self.ticketHistoryService.fetchData()
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        }
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
        let cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! HistoryTableViewCell
        if indexPath.isEqual(self.expandedIndexPath){ // If currently selected cell was just previously selected
            self.expandedIndexPath = nil
            cell.commentLabel.hidden = true
        }
        else {
            self.expandedIndexPath = indexPath
            cell.commentLabel.hidden = false
        }
        self.tableView.endUpdates()
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSIndexPath? {
        let cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! HistoryTableViewCell
        cell.commentLabel.hidden = true
        return indexPath
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if indexPath.isEqual(self.expandedIndexPath) {
            return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        }
        return collapsedHeight
    }
}
```

Comment: use this line of code cell.contentView.clipsToBounds = YES;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to have your cell clip subview content that would expand outside of itself:

```
let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! HistoryTableViewCell
cell.clipsToBounds = true
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. A bit off topic, but when should I hide the content? The additional cell content disappears before the collapsing animation is finished. Can I get the content to disappear just like it appears?

Comment: @drewanton You could just consider not hiding it, since it won't appear with `clipsToBounds` enabled. Alternatively, you could set its `alpha` to `0` inside a `UIView` animation block.