# User Creation Form just Like iOS Contact Creation working behind this?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

This Question is asked and it is duplicate but i dont see any answer to that question This is the Link

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37842147/dynamic-uitableview-like-new-contact-in-contacts-app

i need to create this page for profile creation.. If any one have idea about this please share some codings or ideas behind this...

i know uitableView is thier which is static and dynamic... But when i click the + button the height of the cell is increased..

[image]

[image]

Comment: search accordion in ios. You will get an idea

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283169/duplicate-questions

Comment: So.. what's the question?

Comment: @solidcell question is how can i make this using uitableview ?.

Comment: That's not specific enough. You're not asking for an answer, you're wanting someone to type up a whole tutorial for you.  How about you try it first, and when you run into issues, make a question for each specific issue.

Comment: @solidcell i dont need full tutorial for this.. i just need the working behing the (+ add Phone) number. while click in that button it expands the uitableview. Hope you understand my point. :)

Comment: This has been answered already numerous times. Example:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31705854/smooth-uitableview-cell-expansion-with-accordion-style